# Como puedo concatenar dos strings?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Estoy intentando concatenar dos strings que serian el nombre de la marca y el nombre del modelo en una variable llamada $product->name. Lo que realice en mi controlador fue lo siguiente.

Estas lineas se encuentran en el metodo Store de ProductController:

```
$product->model_id = $request->model_id;
$product->brand_id = $request->brand_id;
$product->name = $request->brand_id . " " . $request->model_id;
```

Ahora cuando lo quiero mostrar en la vista hago lo siguiente:

```
<td>{{$product->name}}</td>
```

Y lo que me devuelve en la vista es lo siguiente:

Producto: 1 1

Que por ende esta recibiendo bien los datos porque la marca tiene id 1 y el modelo lo mismo. Ahora como puedo hacer para que en vez de mostrar esos ids me muestre los valores en si?

BrandController:

Estos son los campos que tengo en el controllador de marcas:

```
    $brand = new Brand();
    $brand->brandName = $request->brandName;
```

ModelController:

```
    $model->modelName = $request->modelName;
    $model->brand_id = $request->brand_id;
```

La relacion entre marca y producto se llama "marca" y la relacion entre modelo y marca se llama "modelo"

Comment: Necesitas hacer una consulta a la bd, ¿qué has intentado al respecto?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
$model = Model::find($request->model_id);
$brand = Brand::find($request->model_id);
```

Previo a tus lineas:

```
$product->model_id = $request->model_id;
$product->brand_id = $request->brand_id;
```

Posterior solo debes hacer esto:

```
$product->name = $brand->brandName. " " . $model->modelName;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).